# enum switcher for functions with different signatures

Tags: c++, templates, casting, switch-statement, variadic-templates

many times, it happens to find situations where I have an enum or an int, and I have functions parameterized on the specific enum values / integers. At runtime I have an enum / integer that I use to call the specific function. With some code it should be clearer:

```
template<int i>
struct MyTrait
  {
  void f(int) { return 999;}
  };

template<>
struct MyTrait<1>
  {
  void f(int a, int b) { return 1; }
  };

template<>
struct MyTrait<2>
  {
  static const int ARD = 2;
  void f(int a, int b, int c) { return 100;}
  };

template<>
struct MyTrait<3>
  {
  static const int ARD = 3;
  void f(int a) { return 120;}
  };


template<class... Args>
int switcher(int value, Args... arguments)
  {
  switch(value)
    {
    case indices:
      return MyTrait<1>::f(arguments...);
    case 2:
      MyTrait<2>::f(arguments...);
    case 3:
      MyTrait<3>::f(arguments...);
    default:
       0;
    }
  return 1;
  }

// switcher(3, 10) should call MyTrait<3>::f
```

To make an example of why this can be useful please check [here](https://kfrlib.com/blog/how-c14-and-c17-help-to-write-faster-and-better-code-real-world-examples/)

I'm using C++11 and I've implemented something similar to the cswitch presented in the link I've posted. Problem is that, for now, it only works with function with the same signature. My goal is instead to make it also work  with functions with different signatures, like the ones in the traits of the example.

Primary goal here is performance: same speed as the switch.
Of course, everything would be quite easy if it could have been possible to use the ... operator in the switch, functions that returned (depending on the argument) different values or if the named label gcc extension were a standard feature (alas I've also considered the goto statement as last resort).

I've tried tens of approaches etc but nothing seems to work as I want.. I'm starting to think that at the moment this is impossible.. feel free (I really hope it!!) to contradict me.

The closest solution I've found so far is to create a jump table, store the arguments into a tuple, convert that tuple (the address) to void* and then convert it back in the traits. But there are performance costs also here and I'm not totally sure if this can produce UB.

I would exclude solutions that use MACROS, C++17 features (ideally C++11 only) and non standard features..

Thanks

Comment: If you want to go ahead with your `MyTrait` classes, you can do [something like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7nNs7IwwZHfkeyf9). Does it work for you? Better solutions exist, but you must change the design of your code.

Comment: _Oops! That page can’t be found._

Comment: What do you want to happens if we call `switcher(3, 42, 42, "too many args");` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 good question: we're at runtime during the call, so an exception would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain your `MyTrait` classes, it's a matter of defining a fallback template function for each specialization.
As an example:

```
template<>
struct MyTrait<1> {
    template<typename... Args> static int f(Args&&...) { return {}; }
    static int f(int, int) { return 1; }
};
```

See [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7nNs7IwwZHfkeyf9) a working example.

If you can refactor a bit your code, you can use free functions, tag dispatching and a single fallback functions to avoid compilation errors.
As an example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

template<int>
struct tag {};

int f(tag<1>, int, int) { return 1; }
int f(tag<2>, int, int, int) { return 100;}
int f(tag<3>, int) { std::cout << "&";  return 120; }

template<typename... Args>
auto caller(int, Args&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename... Args>
int caller(char, Args&&... args) {
    return {};
}

template<class... Args>
int switcher(int value, Args&&... arguments) {
    switch(value) {
    case 1:
        caller(0, tag<1>{}, std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
        break;
    case 2:
        caller(0, tag<2>{}, std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
        break;
    case 3:
        caller(0, tag<3>{}, std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
        break;
    default:
        (void)0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    switcher(3, 10);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

After this comment:

> I'm trying to remove that switch, and the solution you proposed has a switch

I'm proposing a slightly modified version that has no longer a switch but relies on recursion and inheritance:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

template<int N> struct tag: tag<N-1> {};
template<> struct tag<0> {};

int f(tag<1>, int, int) { return 1; }
int f(tag<2>, int, int, int) { return 100;}
int f(tag<3>, int) { std::cout << "&";  return 120; }

template<typename... Args>
int f(Args&&...) { return {}; }

template<int N, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<(N == 0), int>
caller(tag<N> t, Args&&... args) {
    return f(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<int N, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<(N > 0), int>
caller(tag<N> t, int value, Args&&... args) {
    return N == value ? f(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...) : caller(tag<N-1>{}, value, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class... Args>
int switcher(int value, Args&&... arguments) {
    return caller(tag<3>{}, value, std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
}

int main() {
    switcher(3, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you for your reply.  Your solution works for sure, but I probably haven't been clear enough of what I'd like to do. I'm trying to remove that switch, and the solution you proposed has a switch :)

Comment: @user3770392 Answer updated, it has no longer a switch now. ;-) ... Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: mate it really seems working! I would just this namespace detail
  {
  template< bool B, class T = void >
  using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B,T>::type;
  }  to make it compile for C++11.  Now I have to understand why that works, and if there is any performance overhead compared to the switch.. but mate, awesome awesome solution! do you think this approach would work for the traits style too?

Comment: I've ran some tests without many optimizations and the tag method is 23% slower compared to the standard switch approach

Comment: @user3770392 Well, it makes sense, in the worst case you have many function calls instead of a jump directly to the right location. You cannot have your cake and it eat. ;-)

Comment: with optimizations it reaches 50% overhead :/   @skypjack yes, that's true :) my idea was in fact to create a kind of jump table, using an union of function pointers (so each element of the table has the same size). It would have been quite easy if inheritance and union were feasible.. Another idea I had is to store the functions addresses in same contiguous struct, store (at compile time) their offset from a base address and by means of some metaprogramming arcane stuff combined with a jump table, go directly to the corresponding function (using some previously computed offset).

Comment: @user3770392 You are dealing with runtime values. You can do whatever you want at compile-time, but you cannot have it solved in any case. That's sadly true in your case. I'm sorry, but I hope this answer helps you a bit. ;-)

Comment: you deserve the best answer as you were the only one that tried to solve it. Yes, but you know.. I think that there must be a way.. if you think about it, even if it is runtime, using a compile-time computed jump table you have no overhead (as you know, the compiler, internally if possible creates a jump table for the switch)

Comment: @user3770392 Uhm, not exactly the same. Unless you create a (let me say) _jump array_ of a fixed size known at compile-time, using a table would lead to allocations on the dynamic storage and will introduce jumps in memory that don't affect your code in case of a switch.

Comment: yes, first solution was about an array of fixed size (max of the functions pointers size), for the second one instead my idea was to use the input value summed to a (at compile time) precomputed (in some way) offset to access to the correct location.. (don't know if theorically feasible)

Comment: I've tried to test it again.. it seems that with some other tests there's not overhead.. I'll try shielding the CPU and execute the tests in this way. Theoretically the tag should be optimized away by the compiler.. let's see what the new tests say